# How to publish MVC3 razor with WCF service on IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, wcf-ria-services

I have created a service-oriented MVC3 application in Visual Studio 2010. I have used layered architecture for my application. It has a separate project for WCF Services,and separate projects for BLL and DAL, and also one for Entities. Now I want to publish my MVC application on IIS 7.5. I have Windows 7 Home Premium, and I use SQL Server 2008 R2 for my database. How can I publish it in IIS 7.5?

Note: I have created library projects for Entities, BLL, and DAL and use MVC3 for web project and WCF Service Application for WCF services.

I already tried to publish it by using [this tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/04/22/test-you-asp-net-mvc-or-webforms-application-on-iis-7-in-30-seconds.aspx), but when I run the application in a browser, it does not load my Javascript, jquery and CSS files, and it give `Network error 404 file not found`.

Comment: Did you used Url.Content in your mvc application?

Comment: we have the similar project structure.When deploying on IIS, jquery validation n css stopped working.. Later, fixed by specifying Url.Content for any file reference.

Answer (score 0):

Use, @Url.Content("~/blah/blah") to convert the relative path to an application absolute path.

Comment: Thanks for your help.now it remove the error of js and css files but it still give the error file not found about controller's methods.it not hit the controller methods which i write in my application to save my data or to get data from database.what i can do here to remove this problem.

Comment: Please provide ur some sample code. Are you using area in mvc application?